# iPhone application for making notes about sound script when on location

Tags: workflow, recommendations, location-recording, location-audio, location-sound

I'm looking for software that can make a professional sound script  and/or could be used to take notes just for myself with short cuts.

For example: false take, airplane, noise take etc...

I don't want to type in excel all the time. Does software like this exist?

Comment: Could you explain the idea better? Simply note-taking app is default iOS "Notes", why don't use it?

Comment: because i don't want to TYPE! i would make script like ZAXCOM stuff do. U have presets, and u just push button, the take number is always jump etc etc...

Comment: Its interesting, I'm learning iOS development at the moment and it can be good idea for app. If you explain it better, or give any examples, I can try to do it.

Comment: i write u on facebok

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you really looking for, but Sound Devices made app for I-phone 
 "CL WIFI" in witch you can make sound report, and manage your metadata. But like I said it's for Sound Devices

Answer (score 1):

heres is the solution! thats what i wanted.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sound-report-writer/id492004803?mt=8